# How can I scramble the name of function in vbScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to hide a name of function in source code when defining the function. I have tested the logic below to separate the name into two parts but does not work:

```
function convertName(x)
    convertName= x & "tion"
end function

function convertName("myFunc")(text)
    convertName("myFunc")= text
end function

response.write myFunction("test")
```

Is there another way to scramble the name of function?

Comment: What do you want to scramble? Funcion definition, function call, both?

Comment: As I wrote above, When I call the function I call it by full name. I want to scramble the name of function when defining the function. @MCND

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you even want to do that?

Comment: I have wrote a hash function for sensitive data. I want make it as much as possible for hackers to recover those hashed data even if they have access to source code.@AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Don't do that. If your hash function allows reverting the hash when the code is known the algorightm is useless. Cryptographic hashes are one-way functions, meaning the operation MUST NOT be reversible. It's not advisable in general to try and roll your own crypto. Stick to implementations that have been tried and verified.

Comment: My data should be recoverable. I use it to store phone and credit card numbers. Sorry I am not sure if HASH is the correct name for it... @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: In that case hash would be the wrong term indeed. You need an encryption algorithm. However, for encryption algorithms the security should also not depend on the algorithm being secret, but only on the encryption key. This is called "Kerckhoff's Principle". And it's still not advisable to roll your own crypto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading OP question comments I'm sure this is not what OP needs (Ansgar Wiechers is completely right, this just offuscates code but does not provide any security at all), but it is a sample of a way on how to handle what has been requested.

Just in case someone could find it useful, the basic idea is

```
Sub scrambledName( data )
    WScript.Echo data
End Sub 

    Set originalName = GetRef("scrambledName")
    originalName "this is a test"
```

That is, we use a variable with the original name to hold a reference to the code behind the scrambled name.

As a sample:

```
Option Explicit

' Scrambled named code
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Sbesttu29348( inputText )
    WScript.Echo "data=" & inputText
End Sub 

Function Fceinnostttu6953( a, b, c)
    Fceinnostttu6953 = a + b + c
End Function 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Map original names to scrambled ones
    prepareFunctions Array( "testSub", "testFunction" )

    ' Call functions using original names
    testSub "this is a test"
    WScript.Echo testFunction(1, 2, 3)


'Scramble handling code
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Function used to find a scrambled name for the original function
' This simply concatenates input text sorted characters with a simple hash
Function scramble( inputText )
Dim a(256), i, s, h
    For i = 1 To LenB( inputText )
        s = AscB(MidB(inputText, i, 1)) 
        If s > 0 Then a(s) = a(s) & Chr(s)
        h = ((h\2)Xor(((h And 1)*65535)And&hffff))+s
    Next
    scramble = Trim(Join(a,"")) & h
End Function 

' Map original names to scrambled names
' It just defines new variables for the original names pointing to the scrambled names
Sub prepareFunctions( aFunctions )
Dim f, s
    For Each f in aFunctions
        s = s & "Set " & f & "=GetRef(""" & scramble(f) & """)" & vbCrLf
    Next 
    ExecuteGlobal s
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```